# Randomly pick an element in every N elements in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How to randomly pick an element for every N elements in a numpy 1D array?

For example, I have a numpy array `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]` and I want to randomly pick one element in every two elements. One example is `[1,4,5,7,10]`, which means `1` is randomly selected in `[1,2]`, `4` is randomly selected from `[3,4]`, and so on.

I tried to reshape and shuffle the array but I cannot find an elegant way to do it without a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the length divisible by window/group length, we can reshape to a 2D array with the length as the number of cols and then select one random element per row  -

```
def random_pick(a, W):
    b = a.reshape(-1,W)
    idx = np.random.randint(0,b.shape[1], len(b))
    return b[np.arange(len(idx)), idx]
```

Sample run -

```
In [17]: a
Out[17]: array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10])

In [18]: np.random.seed(0)

In [19]: random_pick(a, W=2)
Out[19]: array([ 1,  4,  6,  7, 10])
```

**Compact version**

This also translates to a more compact version -

```
In [81]: W = 2

In [82]: np.random.seed(0)

In [83]: a[np.random.randint(0,W,len(a)//W) + np.arange(0,len(a),W)]
Out[83]: array([ 1,  4,  6,  7, 10])
```

**Generic window length**

To make it generic so that any window length could be fed, it would modify to -

```
def random_pick_generic(a, W):
    L = W*(len(a)//W)
    b = a[:L].reshape(-1,W)
    idx = np.random.randint(0,b.shape[1], len(b))
    out = b[np.arange(len(idx)), idx]
    if len(a[L:])>0:
        out = np.r_[out, np.random.choice(a[L:])]
    return out
```

Sample run -

```
In [50]: a
Out[50]: array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10])

In [51]: np.random.seed(0)

In [52]: random_pick_generic(a, W=2)
Out[52]: array([ 1,  4,  6,  7, 10])

In [53]: np.random.seed(0)

In [54]: random_pick_generic(a, W=3)
Out[54]: array([ 1,  5,  7, 10])
```

**Extend to `3D` case : [batch_size, time_step, channel]**

The solution assuming divisible window length `random_pick` would modify to -

```
b = a.reshape(-1,a.shape[1]//W,W,a.shape[2])
idx = np.random.randint(0,b.shape[2], b.shape[1])
out = b[:,np.arange(len(idx)), idx]
```

Comment: How about a more general case? Say, the original array has shape `[batch_size, time_step, channel]` and only do the operation on the `time_step` dimension.